# Magento Secure/Unsecure Items During Checkout

Tags: security, magento, https

Magento 1.6

I'm looking for the correct way, to place images on a template, that are secured during a secure session, and unsecured, during an unsecure session.  I've searched here and on the web and the only solution I have come to find is to use this call:

echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/imagename.jpg', array('_secure'=>true));

However, this ALWAYS loads the image in https, even when you are not in an https environment.

There has to be a dynamic way of setting this up.

Any help / insight available is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: array('_secure'=>true) will force the url to always be https

Comment: Doesn't `$this->getSkinUrl('images/imagename.jpg');` behave as you wish to?

Comment: Do you see this behavior if you disable full page cache and block html cache?

Comment: Thank you Andrey Tserkus, you're solution solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
array('_forced_secure'=>true)
```

Check :

> core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php